# Do the DJI Phantom 3 & 4 produce the same amount of fish-eye as previous Phantoms?

Tags: distortion, fisheye, aerial-photography

I'm wondering if the generation 3 and 4 of the DJI Phantom are still producing the same fish-eye effect on photography as the Phantom vision 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fisheye went out when the Phantom 3 was released.
The Phantom 3 & 4 have rectilinear wideangle lenses with no fisheye distortion.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the specs of the DJI Phantom 3 and 4, the lens is described as:

> - FOV 94° 20 mm (35 mm format equivalent) f/2.8
> - Focus at ∞

The Phantom 2 on the current DJI website comes with a GoPro Hero4 Black, which (if you're shooting 16x9) has a 118.2º HFOV (the narrower fields of view settings are done by cropping).

So, I'd say that, no, it's probably not going to be giving you much fisheye to go with the integrated camera on the Phantom 3 and 4.  [Footage on Youtube from the Phantom 4](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Phantom%204%20DJI%20footage%20from%20) pretty much bears this out.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an "effect". It is the lens most small action cameras use.

Why? Because you normally do not use a viewfinder, or tripod. You intend to take aerial views, landscape, etc. A normal drone is not a spy cam.